# why i'm getting this error "check the logs for full command output" when i'm installing dlib?

Tags: python, installation, face-recognition, dlib, python-3.9

I'm trying to install `dlib` on vertual studio code but the following error is displayed:

```
 Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iotpp637\\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iotpp637\\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qzdzy48q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iotpp637\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\   
    Complete output (60 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iotpp637\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iotpp637\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iotpp637\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9 -A x64'
    -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):



      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


      You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
      are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
      that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
      development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


      !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!




    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iotpp637\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup  
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 546, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iotpp637\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iotpp637\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call 
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iotpp637\\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iotpp637\\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.9', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\acer\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iotpp637\\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.9', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iotpp637\\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-iotpp637\\dlib_cbdb8998ebb54dee8cad48a70a8a0f3c\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 
'"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qzdzy48q\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Additional note: I installed `cmake` and tried again but nothing change.

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted (grey tick mark on the left of the answer) and upvoting it if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

The error is obvious from the error message you got:

> You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If
> you
> are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
> that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
> development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.

You need to install **Visual Studio for C++* from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus/) and rerun the installation so that the C++ extension to Python can get built.

You can avoid that using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) where the [`dlib` package is available](https://anaconda.org/menpo/dlib) already compiled (but for the moment not for Python 3.9).

Answer (score 0):

**you can use the following method to avoid installing the "Huge" IDE (VS) or the Anaconda.**

Many binaries depend on  Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 for Python 3

so, please try to use the following codes to solve it

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

if you are not succeed to solve this problem,

then you can try to use this link [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](http://The%20latest%20supported%20Visual%20C++%20downloads%20https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) to install this problem